# Spaces replaced by =20 after extracting text from email

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, imap, imaplib

I tried to get the text of a received gmail, using the email and imaplib modules in python. After decoding with utf-8 and after getting the payload of the message, all the spaces are still replaced by =20. Can I use another decoding step in order to fix this?

The code is the following: (I got it from a youtube tutorial - https://youtu.be/Jt8LizzxkPU )

``

```
import email
import imaplib



username = "abc"
password = "123"

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
mail.login(username,password)

mail.select("inbox")

result, data = mail.uid("search", None,"ALL")

inbox_item_list = data[0].split()

for item in inbox_item_list:
    #most_recent = inbox_item_list[-1]
    #oldest = inbox_item_list[0]

    result2, email_data = mail.uid('fetch',item,'(RFC822)') 

    raw_email = email_data[0][1].decode("utf-8")

    email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email)

    to_ = email_message['To']
    from_ = email_message['From']
    subject_ = email_message['Subject']

    counter = 1
    for part in email_message.walk():
        if part.get_content_maintype() == "multipart":
            continue
        filename = part.get_filename()
        if not filename:
            ext = ".html"
            filename = "msg-part-%08d%s" %(counter, ext)
        counter += 1   

    #save file
    content_type = part.get_content_type()
    print(subject_)
    print (content_type)
    if "plain" in content_type:
        print(part.get_payload())
    elif "html" in content_type:
        print("do some beautiful soup")
    else:
        print(content_type)
```

``

Comment: Post the relevant part of your code/script.  It looks like not reversed quoted-printable encoding.  Rule out "problems" in your code before blaming somebody else.

Comment: the hard way: decode various e-mail parts manually e.g., `=20` hints at `quopri.decodestring(b'=20')`. Or you could pass the whole e-mail instead: `email.message_from_string(email_text)` that could decode different parts using appropriate decoding methods

Comment: I think, I already did the step with ``email.message_from_string(email_text)``. So I don't think, that the problem is linked to this particular step. And @AnFi thanks for your answer, but I am not blaming anybody. I am just searching for a way to rule out problems in my code. ^^

Comment: if the spaces are the only problem why not just replace all `'=20'` with `' '`

Comment: Yes, that could work. But what if there is a text, that actually contains =20s intentionally ? I mean I could do it but it is not that clean, right ?

Comment: Send yourself some mail containing the word naïve, spelt thus, and containing any 100-character word. It'll contain more other sequences starting with =. You need to decode the QP properly.

Comment: Also, use the phrase `=20` in your mail. Then you can see that if one character can be encoded, then another can as well.

Comment: Ok, so should i manually replace it(.replace("=20"," "), or is there a tool or command for doing this "QP decoding"? Sorry, if the question seems stupid, but I haven't worked with this encoding-decoding yet.

Comment: The Python3 email libraries can do it automatically for you.  Use message_from_bytes to start.

Comment: Try to use high level lib: https://pypi.org/project/imap-tools/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to `import quopri`, and then when you get the content of the email body (or whatever text that has the `=20s` inside), you can use `quopri.decodestring()`

I do it like this

`quopri.decodestring(part.get_payload())`

But do keep in mind that this is if you quite specifically want to decode from `quoted-printable`. Normally I would say the answer of @jfs is neater.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete code example of how a simple email (that contains both a literal `=20` as well as `=20` sequence that should be replaced by a space) could be decoded:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import email.policy

email_text = """Subject: =?UTF-8?B?dGVzdCDwn5OnID0yMA==?=
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo=
oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong=20word
=3D20
^ line starts with =3D20
emoji: <=F0=9F=93=A7>"""
msg = email.message_from_string(
    email_text, policy=email.policy.default
)
print("Subject: <{subject}>".format_map(msg))
assert not msg.is_multipart()
print(msg.get_content())
```

### Output

```
Subject: <test  =20>
loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong word
=20
^ line starts with =20
emoji: <>
```

`msg.walk()`, `part.get_payload(decode=True)` could be used to traverse more complex `EmailMessage` objects. See [`email` Examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html).

Comment: Thanks for the coding example, but I think, that my code above already included th email.message_from_strings step. The =20s appear anyways.

Comment: @Chris761: look at the complete code example above ^ Do you see `=20` before the `word` word in the `email_text`? Do you see that it is replaced by the space in `msg.get_content()`? `message_from_string()` returns you an object (`EmailMessage`). You have to call its methods such as `get_content()` to get specific parts that you need.